Add text information directly to the viewport for 5 sec
I am trying to add text information directly to the viewport so that it would be displayed for 5 seconds after the button is pressed and then disappear. I have not been able to realize this using timers yet. The script below removes text information when the mouse is moved.
Please tell me how to realize this initial task with the help of timers. If this is not possible in principle, please tell me how to make it so that the script below does not increase the brightness of the information line displayed in the viewport when clicking again.
import bpy
import time
import blf
import functools

def draw_callback_px(self, context, op):
    font_id = 0
    blf.color(font_id,1,1,1,0.7)
    # get viewport size
    header_height = bpy.context.area.regions[0].height # 26px
    npanel_width = bpy.context.area.regions[3].width
    width = bpy.context.area.width - npanel_width 
    height = bpy.context.area.height + header_height
    blf.position(font_id, width/2, height-95, 0)
    blf.size(font_id, 11.0)
    if(op.viewport_visibility_switch == 0):
        blf.draw(font_id, "render")
    elif(op.viewport_visibility_switch == 1):
        blf.draw(font_id, "default")
    elif(op.viewport_visibility_switch == 2):
        blf.draw(font_id, "anim")
    else:
        blf.draw(font_id, "layout")

class KEY_ViewportVisibility(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.key_viewportvisibility"
    bl_label = "KEY_ViewportVisibility"
    viewport_visibility_switch = 0

    def modal(self, context, event):
        try:
            context.area.tag_redraw()
        except AttributeError:
            bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(self._handle, 'WINDOW')
            return {'CANCELLED'}
        # If there is no active 3D view
        if bpy.context.area.type !="VIEW_3D":
            bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(self._handle, 'WINDOW')
            return {'CANCELLED'}
        if event.type == 'MOUSEMOVE':
            bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(self._handle, 'WINDOW')
            return {'CANCELLED'}
        
        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}
    
   
    def execute(self, context):
        op = bpy.types.OBJECT_OT_key_viewportvisibility
        args = (self, context, op)
        self._handle = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw_callback_px, args, 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(KEY_ViewportVisibility)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(KEY_ViewportVisibility)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()


You can check if the operator is running and the handler has been added
Remove the text after 5 sec or MOUSEMOVE
import bpy
import time
import blf
import functools

_handle = None
_self = None
_timer = None

def remove_handle():
    global _handle
    print(_handle)
    if _handle is None:
        return

    bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(_handle, "WINDOW")
    _handle = None

def fin_timer():
    global _self
    if _self is None: return
    try:
        _self.fin_request = True
    except:
        return
    
    _self.add_timer()

def draw_callback_px(self, context, op):
    # catch the operator is dead, when operator fin, switch workspace, ...
    global _self
    try:
        _self.fin_request
    except:
        _self = None
        remove_handle()
        return
    

    font_id = 0
    blf.color(font_id,1,1,1,0.7)
    # get viewport size
    header_height = bpy.context.area.regions[0].height # 26px
    npanel_width = bpy.context.area.regions[3].width
    width = bpy.context.area.width - npanel_width 
    height = bpy.context.area.height + header_height
    blf.position(font_id, width/2, height-95, 0)
    blf.size(font_id, 11.0)
    if(op.viewport_visibility_switch == 0):
        blf.draw(font_id, "render")
    elif(op.viewport_visibility_switch == 1):
        blf.draw(font_id, "default")
    elif(op.viewport_visibility_switch == 2):
        blf.draw(font_id, "anim")
    else:
        blf.draw(font_id, "layout")


class KEY_ViewportVisibility(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.key_viewportvisibility"
    bl_label = "KEY_ViewportVisibility"
    viewport_visibility_switch = 0

    def add_timer(self):
        global _timer
        if _timer is None:
            _timer = bpy.context.window_manager.event_timer_add(0, window=bpy.context.window)
            
    def remove_timer(self):
        global _timer
        if _timer is not None:
            bpy.context.window_manager.event_timer_remove(_timer)
            _timer = None

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if _timer is not None:
            self.remove_timer()

        if event.type == 'MOUSEMOVE' or self.fin_request:
            context.area.tag_redraw()
            self.remove_timer()
            if bpy.app.timers.is_registered(fin_timer):
                bpy.app.timers.unregister(fin_timer)
            return {'FINISHED'}

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def execute(self, context):
        global _handle, _self
        print(_self)
        if _self is not None:
            try:
                _self.fin_request
                # operator already running
                return {"CANCELLED"}
            except:
                pass

        op = bpy.types.OBJECT_OT_key_viewportvisibility
        args = (self, context, op)
        if _handle is None:
            _handle = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw_callback_px, args, 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        _self = self
        self.fin_request = False
        bpy.app.timers.register(fin_timer, first_interval=5.0)
        context.area.tag_redraw()
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(KEY_ViewportVisibility)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(KEY_ViewportVisibility)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()


Thank you so much this is just what I needed. But I had to modify the script a bit because I need to execute this script at the moment when the timer has not been completed yet. So the block "if _self is not None" i placed above line "if _handle is None" in execute function.
